# How can I press 'open' button automatically in dialog box in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button, dialog

I am a beginner in VBA, when I use Application.FilaDialog(msoFileDialogOpen), I can programmatically select a specific file but cannot hit the Open button. I used Sendkeys "{ENTER}" but it doesn't work.

Hope you guys help me hit the button automatically

Here is my code:

```
Sub OpenButton()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .InitialFileName = "my_path"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Eval-txt", "*.csv"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> 0 Then
          Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          .Execute
          Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put you current codes in the post then explain what you need and what problem you are  facing.

Comment: Why are you asking for input from the user if you are just going to click for them? If you already know you want to open the file then there is no need for a dialog box.

Comment: I know, but I need to insert this file into another file so that's why I open dialog.

Comment: I don't need to open the file

Comment: You don't need `FileDialog` here at all.  Explain what you are actually trying to do and someone will suggest the correct method

Comment: Just help me to hit the 'Open' button, thank you!

Comment: if you just want to open a file, just use `workbooks.open`, no need for any dialog.

Comment: @Rosetta `FileDialog` does not open a workbook, so it can't be replaced by `Workbooks.Open`.

Answer (score 0):

`FileDialog` is the function of the human-machine interface which is exclusively dedicated to interact with a human. You don't need to use this function if you don't need any information from a human.

What will be the result of desired "press 'open' button automatically" action? You will get a file name. Considering "programmatically select a specific file", you can get this result just assigning the specific file name to a variable without `FileDialog`.

Thus, the code:

```
Sub OpenButton()
    Dim sFn As String
    sFn = "my_path\afilename.csv" ' afilename - that you "programmatically select a specific file"
End Sub
```

Generally, the first question you need stating and answering yourself is "Is human interaction required at all?". If yes, you need to determine the kind of interaction:

1. Get some information. It can be just confirmation for you programmatically selection of a specific file:

```
  Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
  answer = MsgBox("Pls. confirm the filename " & sFn, vbOKCancel, "File selection")
  If answer = vbOK Then
    ...
```

2. Provide a human information. You can perform this using the status bar:

```
Application.StatusBar = sFn
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileDialog` will return the path to a file that the user selects and nothing else.

To get the file to open you must use `Workbooks.Open` using something like this example:

```
Sub OpenButton()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            .InitialFileName = "my_path"
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Eval-txt", "*.csv"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> 0 Then
                'After the user has hit enter the workbook will open.
                Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
                
                'And display a message showing what's in cell A1 of the first sheet.
                MsgBox wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If it's the same file each time you can tell the code to open it without any interaction from the user:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dbartrup-cook\Documents\SomeFile.csv")
    
    MsgBox wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Or if the filename can be calculated you could use that:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dbartrup-cook\Documents\" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy") & ".csv")
    
    MsgBox wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

End Sub
```

The filename for the last example would be: *C:\Users\dbartrup-cook\Documents\01-Nov-23.csv* today, and *02-Nov-23.csv* tomorrow.